# Helm create configmap with different names from values file

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I'm trying to create configmaps with different names based on the multiPod variable in the values file. If the multiPod variable is set to True, then helm should create 3 CM based on the region and 1 CM based on the key like cm-storage or cm-compute. Please help me in achieving this use case. TIA

configMap.yaml

```
{{- range $keys, $values := $.Values.topicsToRead }}

{{- if $values.multiPod }}
{{- range $values.region }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-{{ . }}
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
{{- end -}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Values.yaml

```
topicsToRead:
  compute:
    multiPod: true
    region:
      - region815
      - region816
      - region817
  storage:
    multiPod: false
    region:
      - region715
      - region716
      - region717
```

Output:

```
❯ helm template -s templates/configmap.yaml .
---
# Source: helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region815
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region816
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region817
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
```

Output I want:

```
❯ helm template -s templates/configmap.yaml .
---
# Source: helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region815
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region816
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region817
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-storage
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to break this up into multiple templates.  You can write a template that produces the ConfigMap content:

```yaml
{{- /* Produce a ConfigMap.  Pass a dictionary with a key "name" as the
       parameter. */ -}}
{{- define "configmap" -}}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
{{ end -}}
```

Once you have this, then you can call it from the outer template.  Since you have it as a separate helper template, you can invoke it without copying the template content even if `multiPod` is false.

```yaml
{{- range $k, $v := $.Values.topicsToRead }}
  {{- if $v.multiPod }}
    {{- range $v.region }}
      {{- include "configmap" (dict "name" (printf "cm-%s" .)) -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- else -))
    {{- include "configmap" (dict "name" (printf "cm-%s" $k)) -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

(I've indented this for readability, but also made sure absolutely every template element has `-` whitespace-control markers.  I've used `$v` as the loop variable name mostly to distinguish from the standard Helm `.Values`.)

The one other trick I've used here is the `dict`.  A Helm template only takes a single parameter.  I'm guessing you're not generating the same fixed content for every single ConfigMap, so what I've done here is to pass a dictionary as the parameter.  I compute its name in the outer template, and then can refer to it as `.name` (the `name` field on the parameter variable `.`) in the inner template.  You can extend this to add more "parameters" by including them in the `dict` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
{{- range $keys, $values := $.Values.topicsToRead }}
{{- if $values.multiPod }}
{{- range $values.region }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-{{ . }}
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
{{- end }}
{{- else }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-{{ $keys }}
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
topicsToRead:
  compute:
    multiPod: true
    region:
      - region815
      - region816
      - region817
  storage:
    multiPod: false
    region:
      - region715
      - region716
      - region717
```

output

```yaml
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region815
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region816
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-region817
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-storage
data:
  features.toml: |
    [features]
    x_enabled = false
```

Comment: I failed to mention important point in the question is that i trimmed the data part in the CM to just 3 lines but my actual CM has 100 lines of data. With the above solution i feel like the raw CM looks cumbersome with the same data in ELSE block. Is there any other alternative for the solution provided? thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that this configuration would be very long. As David Maze mentioned below（David Maze explained it well）, this repetitive code can be extracted and referenced as a [named templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/), and then rendered.